# How can I get data from the Entity Framework if I only know the table name and the column name from which to get the data?

Tags: .net, linq, frameworks, entity

I have a table `Parameters` which contains columns `Id`, `Name`, `TableName`, `ColumnName` among others. The database also contains multiple 'series data' tables which have several, possibly hundreds of columns including a `Timestamp` column. I do not own the db schema. So I cannot change this.

The user must provide the `Name` of the `Parameter`, a `StartTime` and an `EndTime` by means of the GUI. The business logic must return a series of data.

How can I get the data that is in the column and table whose names are `param.TableName` and `param.ColumnName`?

I am currently using a switch statements like this:

```
public List<double> GetData
                    (string paramName, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var param =
            (from p in context.Parameters where p.Name == paramName select p)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        switch (param.TableName)
        {
             case "Table1":
                 return GetTable1Data(columnName, startTime, endTime);
                 break;
             case "Table2":
                 return GetTable2Data(columnName, startTime, endTime);
                 break;
             default:
                 throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

private List<double> GetTable1Data
   (MyEntities context, string columnName, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime) {

    List<double> data = new List<double>();

    switch (columnName)
    {
        case "Parameter1":
            (from d in context.Table1 where d.Timestamp >= startTime && d.Timestamo <= endTime
            order by d.Timestamp select d).ForEach(x => data.Add(d.Parameter1));
            break;
        case "Parameter2":
            (from d in context.Table1 where d.Timestamp >= startTime && d.Timestamo <= endTime
            order by d.Timestamp select d).ForEach(x => data.Add(d.Parameter2));
            break;
       case "Parameter3":
           (from d in context.Table1 where d.Timestamp >= startTime && d.Timestamo <= endTime
           order by d.Timestamp select d).ForEach(x => data.Add(d.Parameter3));
           break;
       default:
           throw new Exception("");
    }

    return data;
}

private List<double> GetTable2Data(MyEntities context, string columnName, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    List<double> data = new List<double>();

    switch (columnName)
    {
        case "Parameter1":
            (from d in context.Table2 where d.Timestamp >= startTime && d.Timestamo <= endTime
            order by d.Timestamp select d).ForEach(x => data.Add(d.Parameter1));
            break;
        case "Parameter2":
            (from d in context.Table2 where d.Timestamp >= startTime && d.Timestamo <= endTime
            order by d.Timestamp select d).ForEach(x => data.Add(d.Parameter2));
            break;
        case "Parameter3":
            (from d in context.Table2 where d.Timestamp >= startTime && d.Timestamo <= endTime
            order by d.Timestamp select d).ForEach(x => data.Add(d.Parameter3));
            break;
        default:
             throw new Exception("");
    }

    return data;

}
```

This duplication seems very wrong.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You could build the query using the information you have in string form and then execute it like this:

```
return db.ExecuteStoreQuery<double>(
    "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN {2} AND {3}",
    columnName,
    tableName,
    startTime,
    endTime).ToList();
```

Pete

Comment: +1, given that we're not looking to return Entity objects, using EF at all seems pointless.

Comment: You should use parameters to avoid possible SQL injection especially since according to OP to of the values are taken directly from the UI

Comment: Very true.  There is an overload to take parameters - I have edited the answer to use this.